# ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:38] Could not find action There is no Action mapped for action name default. - [unknown location]

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, liferay, portlet

I do have a problem when I run my portlet application, I have this error :

```
ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:38] Could not find action There is no Action mapped for action name default. - [unknown location]
```

I'm working with Struts 2.2.1 and Liferay 6.0.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="eleve" extends="struts-portlet-default">
        <action name="ajoutereleves">
            <result>/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="AddEleveAction" class="com.version.projet.actions.AddEleveAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
            <result name="input">/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/JSPs/eleve/addeleve.jsp</result>
            <result>/JSPs/eleve/showseleves.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the `namespace` annotation. How to properly map actions to [namespaces](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Namespaceannotation) look at the following documentation for convention plugin.

Comment: thanks for reply.the problem still persist. because my example is running fine without liferay,but when i configure it to a struts2 portlet i have this problem.