# Autocompleter Struts 2 jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, autocomplete

I have read a lot on this topic & know how it should work but anyhow I am not successful in running code.

The below presented code is running but do not load `JSONObject`.

**Here is my `x.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<sx:head />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Auto complete example</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <h2>Welcome to India</h2>
    <s:url id="optionsUrl" action="g" />

    <sx:autocompleter href="%{#optionsUrl}" loadOnTextChange="true"
        loadMinimumCount="3" value="Florida" keyValue="FL" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is `struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

        <action name="g" class="com.AutoCompleter">
            <result type='json'>
                <param name="root">options</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**Here is my Action Class:**

```
package com;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class AutoCompleter extends ActionSupport {
   public Map<String, String> getOptions() {
       System.out.println("Hello");
      Map<String,String> options = new HashMap<String,String>();
      options.put("Florida", "FL");
      options.put("Alabama", "AL");
      return options;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<sx:head />` should be in the body of the `<head>` tag where the loading javascript is performed. And it should be loaded before any JS tag is ended.

Comment: I did as you said but now it gives
when i add a line 

<s:url id="optionsUrl" action="g" />
 
<s:a href="%{#optionsUrl}">Hello</s:a>      //*****This is added
 
<sx:autocompleter href="%{#optionsUrl}" loadOnTextChange="true"
  loadMinimumCount="3" value="Florida" keyValue="FL" />

When click on Hello
Messages: 
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name g.

Comment: On this theme I have about 100 answers and no one accepted. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16043066/573032

Comment: When the action is called? Just as I click on the autocompleter box or at time of page load.
Please help me It is not being called at all.

Comment: Did you try to manually enter the url for the action that should return json data?